# Unable to Handle Tap, Swipe, Pan, Pinch events for Qt Poppler Library example

Tags: qt, qml

I took the example of the Poppler Library to render PDF on Qt platform. I am trying to write gesture handling for the example.

The example can be downloaded from "doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.zip" URL.

In a nutshell, the example has a DocumentWidget.cpp which is Derived from "QLabel" which in turn derives from QFrame and QWidget.

Now since QLabel is inherited from QWidget I have started implementing for Gesture Handling.

in DocumentWidget.h i have added the below function

```
protected:
 bool event( QEvent* e );
```

in DocumentWidget.cpp constructor
    grabGesture( Qt::TapGesture )

```
bool DocumentWidget :: event( QEvent* e )
{
  if( e->type() == ( Qt :: TapGesture )
     gestureEvent();
}
```

In the above gestureEvent function I try to check if it is Tap and correspondingly planning to handle the tap event. However, In my example the event function is getting called but the tap gesture is being handled.

I have included all the necessary header files. I have forward declared the classes too.

Can you please tell me where am I going wrong. Can't we handle these gestures for QLabel.

Thank You in advance.

Chand.M

Answer (score 0):

You are already checking for `TagGesture` in the event handler. So you need not check it once again in the `gestureEvent()` function. Moreover after consuming the event you have to `return true;` stating that the even has been consumed.

If the even is not a TapGesture then pass it to the QWidget itself like this.

```
 if( e->type() == ( Qt :: TapGesture )
     gestureEvent();
 else
     return QWidget::event(e);
```

You can find documentation on even handling [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/eventsandfilters.html#event-handlers).